# Naked singularities in negative $M$ BTZ black hole geometry

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes, differential-geometry, ads-cft

Consider a BTZ black hole geometry,
\begin{equation}
ds^2=-N(r)^2dt^2+N(r)^{-2}dr^2+r^2(N^\phi dt+d\phi)^2,
\end{equation}
where $M>0$, $N(r)^2=-M+\frac{r^2}{l^2}+\frac{J}{4r^2}$ and $N^\phi(r)=-\frac{J}{2r^2}$.

If we continue $M$ to negative values, we get a naked singularity $r=0$ as there is no horizon.

In     [arXiv:gr-qc/9302012](https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/9302012.pdf), page 9 more precisely, they say that there is an exception if $M=-1$ and $J=0$. So we have an anti-de Sitter space, separated from the continuous black hole spectrum by a mass gap of one unit.

For me we should have physical solutions for every $M<0$ as long as $J=0$. And therefore we can continue the BTZ solution to AdS continuously. Can someone explain me how to find the value $M=-1$ and how come we have naked singularities for other negative $M$?

Thanks :)